# German word for “change the subject” or “swap the cars”

Tags: single-word-request, idiom

When my German grandma wanted everyone to stop talking (arguing really) and change the subject at the dinner table, she used a German word that sounded like *oompsdaggon.*  She said it meant *change the subject* or *swap the cars* in German.  Would anyone out there know this word?

Answer (score 14):

She probably said [**umsteigen**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/umsteigen) ([ˈʊmˌʃtaɪ̯ɡən] ↔ *oompsdaggon*), but that’s merely a guess.

There’s no specific translation, but regarding trains, for instance, *umsteigen* means “change trains”. You also use it when referring to cars.

So she probably encouraged the animated discussion to change subject, to switch to other topics.

While your grandmother surely knew how to baffle the table round, I don’t think it’s a German saying. An established phrase is *Lass uns das Thema wechseln*, simply meaning “Let’s change subject”.

Comment: That is correct - it was over 40 years ago she used to say that.  And it was trains not cars.  Thanks so much brings me such fond memories.

Comment: Or *Themawechsel* or *TW* for modern, even shorter ways of saying it ;)

Comment: "Change the subject" would be "Das Thema ändern". Saying "umsteigen" in those terms would be very strange sounding.

Comment: @swizzledude: There’s plenty of meanings for “change”. Some of them are *ändern*, *wechseln* and *tauschen*. A little less obvious and far more figuratively, *umsteigen* would fit as well, be it with this specific instance alone. Anyhow, I didn’t say nothing ’bout that—please see above. I merely produced *wechseln* for “change”, suggesting an alternative phrase.

Comment: A colloquial American translation might be "Let's switch gears."

Comment: @TomAu: Is it an impartial saying for “changing subject”, or may it be understood as “let’s shift into a lower gear, before we go for the jugular”?

Comment: @dakab: It is an impartial saying. And one that is related to cars or trains.